# Не работает adjustResize

Tags: android, клавиатура, разметка

Всем привет, нужно при открытии клавиатуры поднимать  центральный `LinearLayout`, в тестовом проекте все работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Logo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="100sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Login"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Auth"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:text="Registration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

А в проекте не работает. В проекте одна кнопка и поле для ввода скрыты и появляются в процессе работы

**До**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**После**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:background="#659DDB">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/login_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Skyscrapers"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:id="@+id/logo_official"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="66sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_nick_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AuthInput"
        android:textColorHint="#f7f7f7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_nick"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Имя в игре"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:theme="@style/AuthEdit"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_pass_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AuthInput"
        android:textColorHint="#f7f7f7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Пароль"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:theme="@style/AuthEdit"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Далее"
        android:textColor="#527dad"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/login_btn_auth"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Отмена"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:backgroundTint="#D2352B"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/login_back"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="tt"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Что я не так сделал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

в корневой элемент разметки все-таки заставил подняться нижнюю `View`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.